# Dynamic regression linear models in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, forecasting, dynamic-regression

I have a question regarding Dynamic regression linear models.
I wonder if it is possible to implement a MLR model (in R) using 'lm' and creating lagged values of predictors and dependent variables.
For example, considering the linear regression described at https://www.otexts.org/fpp/5/1 
 ("Forecasting: principles and practice"), can I retrive lagged values for savings, income, etc. and the same output "score" variable and build a model like below?

```
require(dplyr)
log.savings_lag1<-lag(log.savings, 1)
........
score_lag1<-lag(score,1)

fit <- lm(score ~ log.savings + log.income +
log.address + log.employed+ log_savings_lag1,score_lag1, data=creditlog)
```

If this feasible? There is any particular concern I have to be aware?